# jQueryUI draggable disables mouseover/mouseout events for elements with "z-index" values < 0

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, mouseover, mouseout

If a jQuery UI draggable element (#box1) is dragged over an element (#box2) that has z-index set to -1 or below, mouseover and mouseout events won't fire. With z-index set to 0 or above they fire.

CSS:

```
#box1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#box2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 300px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
        $("#box1").draggable();

        $("#box2").mouseover(function(e) {
            $("#box2").css({
                backgroundColor: "green"
            });
        });
        $("#box2").mouseout(function(e) {
            $("#box2").css({
                backgroundColor: "transparent"
            });
        });
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/TTwPj/11/

Without dragging mouseover and mouseout work fine with all z-index-values.

Is there a reason for this behaviour or is it a bug?

Comment: which browser you have this problem?

Comment: Current Firefox and Chromium under Debian.

Comment: Logically that is correct, Element top of another element will be focused to the user and bottom will not focused for the user. If you need to work with bottom element you have to move the top element from there. Note: Don't use z index in a negative values.

Comment: Why not use negative values with z-index? w3schools says expilicitly that this is ok.

Comment: In most of the cases negative value will make the element goes below the body and html element. In your case you need stack of elements so better use positive z-index values.

Answer (score 0):

This "problem" has nothing todo with negative or positiv values of your z-index.
In this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TTwPj/23/

```
#box1 {
    z-index: 2;
}

#box2 {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

you can see I set some positive values and the mousover still not firing. This is how z-index work.

If you want to achive a mouseover while dragging over the droppable element you can use the droppable event:

```
over: function( event, ui ) {}
```

to add a CSS class or style to show some visible "mouseover" effect.